# Reinstalling windows while having linux (ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, uninstall

I have installed windows XP and then decided to install Ubuntu. Ubuntu is now set as default OS (it automatically loads Ubuntu).

My question is how can I reinstall Windows XP without removing Ubuntu? Windows XP is installed in separate partition. I am concerned that if I start reinstalling Windows XP, Ubuntu will be deleted.

Comment: Do you know that WindowsXP support will end in April 8th?

Comment: What does that mean? No updates or no windows at all?

Comment: This means No Support and No Updates. More details on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx

Comment: As long as you have at least 1GB of RAM you should use Windows 7. What programs are you running on Windows XP? Have you tried running them with wine on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check how your disk is set up. If you don't have any NTFS primary partitions, you'll have to make one (or resize the one with the most free space). Then you install Windows XP on that NTFS partition. Once you've done that, boot into a live system (live DVD, or USB flash drive), then run `grub-install` During the install, GRUB will detect your Windows and Ubuntu partitions and create entries for both. Afterwards, you can change the configuration of how you want to boot your system (the length of the auto-boot countdown, and what's the first boot option if countdown is reached).

Answer (score 0):

At the disk setup screen when installing Windows you will need to choose the partition where Windows is currently installed and leave the Ubuntu partition(s) alone. Windows will override the grub boot loader. After you install Windows you will need to do as ki2ne suggests: run `grub-install` from a live Ubuntu CD/DVD/Flash drive.